# Laravel problemas para redirecionar depois de autenticar?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, auth

Estou começando a aprender a usar o `Framework` `Laravel` e estou com um problema com o direcionamento após o login, estou usando o sistema de login do próprio `Framework`.

Para aprender a usar o `Framework` estou criando um blog simples e na hora de realizar o login esta direcionando para o caminho `/admin` mesmo eu alterando o atributo `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard'`;

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser pois não consegui encontrar o **bug**?

Conforme solicitado pelos amigos abaixo, segue o código das rotas e da classe onde alterei o atributo redirectTo.

routes/web.php

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {
        Route::get('/','DashboardController@index');
    });
```

app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
    * Where to redirect users after login.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
    * Create a new controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
```

App/Http/Controllers/HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Gabriel, você pode colocar o seu arquivo de rotas aqui pro pessoal te ajudar melhor? Onde você tá mudando o `$redirectTo`?

Comment: Poste o seu código @gabrielguedes, mesmo que seja o que vem no Laravel e em cima disso explique o seu procedimento, existe dois lugares para mudar dependendo do jeito que esteja fazendo vai causar essa confusão mesmo, lembro não é `bug` do `Laravel`. Qual é a versão do seu Laravel isso também é importante.

Comment: Com as recentes atualizações do `Laravel`, é importante postar qual versão exatamente está utilizando também...

Comment: A versão do Laravel é a 5.3

Comment: Tente rodar o comando `php artisan cache:clear`